# join multiple columns with single column in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables as follows

t1:

```
id  code    field1  field2
1   1000    a1111   a2222
2   2000    b1111   b2222
3   1000    a3333   a4444
4   2000    b3333   b4444
5   2000    b5555   b6666
6   3000    c1111   c2222
7   3000    c3333   c4444
8   3000    c5555   c6666
```

t2:

```
t2id    t1_code     var1
1   1000           xxxx
2   2000           yyyyy
3   3000           zzz
4   3000           mmm
```

i want the result table as:

```
code    field1  field2      t1_code     var1
1000    a3333   a4444       1000            xxxx
1000    a1111   a2222           null            null
2000    b3333   b4444       2000            yyyyy
2000    b5555   b6666           null            null
2000    b1111   b2222       null            null
3000    c1111   c2222       3000            mmm
3000    c3333   c4444       3000            zzz
3000    c3333   c4444       null            null
```

i tried :

```
SELECT t1.code, t1.field1, t1.field2, t2.t1_code, t2.var1
FROM t2, t1
WHERE t1_code = code
ORDER BY code
```

is not giving me the answer.

Please help...

Comment: i am a learner please help me sir.Please post the full query

Comment: How do you expect this to work? There isn't enough information to form a bijection between t1 rows and t2 rows, and SQL doesn't know how to just fill in columns "until they fit". Joining is one-to-one or one-to-all-that-match.

Comment: please post the query

Comment: @GordonLinoff no it's not. There are rows in `t2` for every `code` in `t1`, the nulls aren't there because of an outer join.

Comment: I have tried to decode the logic behind the nulls.. but there is no consistent applicable rule for the desired "results". So, OP should explain in more detail what he wants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, you want the join to go to the "first" matching row in t1 (where "first" means lowest id).

Here is almost a way to do it:

```
SELECT t1.code, t1.field1, t1.field2, t2.t1_code, t2.var1
FROM t1 left outer join
     (select t1.code, min(id) as minid
      from t1
      group by t1.code
     ) t1min
     on t1.id = t1min.minid left outer join
     t2
     on t2.t1_code = t1min.code;
```

What this does is join the original table to another table to find the minimum `id` for each code.  By joining on the `id`s, the `t1min.code` will only have values at the min ids.  The final join just brings in the code for these.

EDIT:

The actual problem is a bit more complicated.  I think the best way is simply to enumerate the values in each table and do the join with two keys:

```
select t1.code, t1.field1, t1.field2, t2.t1_code, t2.var1
from (select t1.*,
             @rn1 := if(@code = code, @rn1 + 1, 1) as rn, @code := code
      from t1 cross join
           (select @rn1 := 0, @code := '') const
      order by code, id
     ) t1 left outer join
     (select t2.*,
             @rn2 := if(@code = t1_code, @rn2 + 1, 1) as rn, @code := t1_code
      from t2 cross join
           (select @rn2 := 0, @code := '') const
      order by t1_code, t2id
     ) t2
     on t1.code = t2.t1_code and t1.rn = t2.rn
order by t1.id;
```

Comment: Is there anyway to overcome the duplicate row in the last code 3000

Comment: @user3202095 . . . What do you want to happen?  Do you really want 1 out of 3 assigned to the "2000"s and 2 out of 3 for the "3000"s?

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff , Yes exactly Sir

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff , based on the no of records in t2 for that particular code

Comment: @user3202095 . . . I see the problem now.  You *could* have explained it better.  It is an interesting problem but difficult to understand all the nuances.

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff , the above query says " Unknown column 'code' in 'field list' "

Comment: I would like to get the result table exactly as shown in the question by joining two tables t1 and t2

Comment: Are you saying that this code does not work?  If not, explain how.  Also, consider putting your data up on SQL Fiddle.  Makes it much easier to work on a problem.

Comment: ,As you suggested i had created the table in sql fiddle : sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a8bed/4

Comment: @user3202095 . . . I fixed your column name `ti_code` instead of `t1_code`.  The version in the answer now works.  You can see it at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a3701/6.